# Capture subject line from Outlook email into mailto link in signature

Tags: html, vba, outlook, mailto

I am helping someone working in operations to set up an email signature which includes a link to escalate to a higher official in case of any displeasure. While I can use a mailto: to link to the official's email id, I want to also capture the subject of the email to capture details like Service Ticket number and any other title that is in the email subject.

What I mean to say in a nutshell is - when a user clicks on the link, he would get a new Outlook compose mail window with the same subject. Using simple mailto: with manually changing subject line wont help. Looking for some tips here - am open to look at dynamic options like VB code or something but it has to be via Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Include a placeholder in the signature's link (e.q. `mailto:somebody@domain.demo?subject=xyzq`), when Application.ItemSend event fires, look at the MailItem.HTMLBody property and replace the placeholder (xyzq above) with the value of the MailItem.Subject property. You might need to encode spaces and special characters.

Comment: Am sorry a bit lost, you mean to create a VB code? I understand the logic you explained but part of my question is also to understand a way to achieve it. Am novice when it comes to VB or Macros.

Comment: You will need to create the Application_ItemSend event handler in your VBA module. Have you tried that?

Comment: Not yet Dmitry, I have a VBA guy who is helping me with the coding and am looking for this information to get as much to him as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The mailto: command doesn't allows to specify any custom information for Outlook. Read more about the mailto scheme in [RFC2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368).

If you are new to VBA, I'd recommend starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article which explains the basics.

Comment: Oh yes I completely know that and this is not one of those posts about adding more functionality to mailto:.. thanks for the link though